# Angular2 [style.boxShadow] with multiple shadows not working

Tags: angular

I have the following component:

```
//our root app component
import {Component, NgModule, VERSION} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div [style.backgroundColor]="backgroundColor"
         [style.boxShadow]="boxShadow">
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  backgroundColor = 'red';
  boxShadow = '0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0,0,0,.2), 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.14), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.12);'
  constructor() {
    this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

The `backgroundColor` works fine but the `boxShadow` doesn't get applied when there are comma separated multiple values. Is there a way to make this work? I wanted to let the user choose the `box-shadow` property, and the I would like to claim "just input any valid css".

Here's the plunker: https://embed.plnkr.co/IEGPshB3FcB1QoZDp018/

Answer (score -1):

Check this it works

https://plnkr.co/edit/XmunNluzwYnxFQw8gD5q?p=preview

```
export class App {
  name:string;
  backgroundColor = 'red';
  boxShadow = '10px 10px 5px #888888' //you can try with this also -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black
  constructor() {
    this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`
  }
}
```

Comment: No reason for DownVote Cool Sometimes i dnt understand